# C++: How to modify a files 'created' timestamp?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I need to modify the 'created' (if exists), 'modified' and 'accessed' timestamps of a file. Ideally this would be a platform-independent solution.

I've looked around the boost libraries but I can't see anything relevant. The nearest I've found to something relevant is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/timestamp.aspx?msg=1300823#xx1300823xx) for Windows.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: That's a classic interview question for Unix admins, "how to view file creation timestamp?". The answer is: there is no such thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never used them but i guess that you are looking for the attribute functions: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/reference.html#Attribute-functions 

There are also functions for the last modification:

```
template <class Path> std::time_t last_write_time(const Path& p);
template <class Path> void last_write_time(const Path& p, const std::time_t new_time);
```

Comment: Note: The second of these will set the last modification time, in case that's what is desired.

Comment: And how this answer help with modification of 'created' flag time?

Comment: @killdaclick afaik there is no functionality in boost which provides the creation time. i think if you want that you would have to write your own function with different implementations for the supported platforms

Comment: Probably because creation time doesn't exist in *nix platforms.

Answer (score 3):

[Another](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?automodule=blog&blogid=114&showentry=881), slightly simpler code snippet for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`utime`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/utime.html) function and [`utimbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/File-Times.html) struct. The method is available in Windows but is named with a leading underscore as [`_utime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wacf567%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Update: `utime` only allows you to change the *access* and *modification* times (via `utimbuf`'s `actime` and `modtime` fields). This is most likely because many Unix-style file systems do not record the *creation* time anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not all popular filesystems support 'created' and 'accessed' timestamps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata

Windows filesystems do, but it might not be a good idea to depend on them now if you need portability. Looking at that table I get an impression that there is a trend to add support for them in newer filesystems though.